# Dynamic SOQL query giving error

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I am trying to execute below query and getting error which says Unexpected token IN
Can someone please help to understand what is wrong here.

```
String str = 'SELECT Name FROM Account';
String str1='WHERE';
String str3='Name IN (\'test\',\'test9\')';
list<Account> accclist=Database.query(str+str1+str3);
system.debug(accclist);
```

However when I run this below one it runs perfectly fine.

```
list<Account> accclist=Database.query('SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN (\'test\',\'test9\')');
```

Comment: You do not need to use a dynamic soql query here, it's only making things more complicated for you. The general advice for everyone is to use static queries _until you know that you can't use them_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code.

1.Add spaces before `WHERE` & `Name` clauses.

2.Since you are using single quotes in condition , you will need to escape it as below :

```
str3='Name IN (\'test\',\'test9\')';
```

More info - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm

3.Also , `Database.query` returns List of `sObjects` which needs type casting.

Final code will look as below:

```
String str = 'SELECT Name FROM Account'; 
String str1=' WHERE'; 
String str3=' Name IN (\'test\',\'test9\')'; 
List<Account> accclist=(List<Account>)Database.query(str+str1+str3); 
system.debug(accclist);
```

Please refer the [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) for more info.

Comment: the values under IN will be received dynamically(i.e. test and test9)..and I need to store then in a string and pass it on to the final string which is string3...I tried this option but getting error. Please help to get this resolved as this is required urgently:              String str = 'SELECT Name FROM Account'; 
String str1=' WHERE';
String strnew='test';
String new1='test9';
String str3=' Name IN ('\''+strnew+'\''+','+'\''+new1+'\')'; 
List<Account> accclist=(List<Account>)Database.query(str+str1+str3); 
system.debug(accclist);

Comment: You can use below code, here we are using list with variable binding in dynamic SOQL : 

String str = 'SELECT Name FROM Account'; 
String str1=' WHERE'; 

List<String> names = new List<String>{'test','test9'};
    
    for(String str: names) {
        str = '\''+str+'\'';
    }
String str3=' Name IN :names'; 
List<Account> accclist=(List<Account>)Database.query(str+str1+str3); 
system.debug(accclist);

Comment: I remodified the code like below and it worked..thanks for the help so far:                     String str = 'SELECT Name FROM Account'; 
String str1=' WHERE';
String strnew='test';
String new1='test9';
String str3=' Name IN'+ '('+'\''+strnew+'\''+','+'\''+new1+'\')'; 
List<Account> accclist=(List<Account>)Database.query(str+str1+str3); 
system.debug(accclist);

Comment: ok . I had also added it in my previous comment. But as @DerekF pointed out, we do not need dynamic SOQL in this scenario.

Comment: Understood..Thanks @Rohit for your help and advice in this regard.